# How to remove multi index after groupby pandas

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, hierarchical

I started with:

```
                     DISCH_PRESS  stage
timestamp                              
2017-11-17 07:10:09  6241.483887   14.0
2017-11-17 07:10:12  6353.102051   14.0
2017-11-17 07:10:15  6673.465820   14.0
2017-11-17 07:10:17  7089.970215   14.0
2017-11-17 07:10:20  7449.266113   14.0
```

I performed the following operation to resample the timestamp after each stage was grouped:

```
df = df.groupby(['stage']).resample('1S').asfreq()
```

Now my data looks like this:

```
                           DISCH_PRESS  stage
stage timestamp                              
1.0   2017-11-18 23:18:20  4728.775879    1.0
      2017-11-18 23:18:21          NaN    NaN
      2017-11-18 23:18:22          NaN    NaN
      2017-11-18 23:18:23  5109.784180    1.0
      2017-11-18 23:18:24          NaN    NaN
```

I want to remove the stage row index. My data should look like:

```
                     DISCH_PRESS  stage
timestamp                              
2017-11-18 23:18:20  4728.775879    1.0
2017-11-18 23:18:21          NaN    NaN
2017-11-18 23:18:22          NaN    NaN
2017-11-18 23:18:23  5109.784180    1.0
2017-11-18 23:18:24          NaN    NaN
```

When I tried searching for solutions I mostly found solutions to multi column indexing, I tried adapting those solutions for my application, see the following inputs and resulting errors:

```
df.MultiIndex.droplevel(level=0)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'MultiIndex'

df.droplevel(level=0)
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'droplevel'

dframe.reset_index()
ValueError: cannot insert timestamp, already exists

df.rows.droplevel()
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'row'
```

Obviously I am using these methods incorrectly. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Need `dframe = dframe.reset_index(level=0, drop=True)`

Comment: Thank you! Just missing the arguments I guess... I don't know why I didn't find the solution you referenced during my search. Thanks again.